# Activate android LED without turning off the screen

Tags: java, android, screen, led

Good day,

So I am deploying a simple LED notification to activate the android LED(RGB color). It works fine for me so far, somehow I realize that the LED notification activities only active when i turned my android screen off. Is there any other way to activate the LED while my android screen are turn on?